# C++: Function for Max Array Value working improperly

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I am trying to write a function for finding the maximum value in an array, without using any c++ built in functions like sort, max_element, etc.

I have developed this code below, and it does eventually decide on a "max value", but it's not always correct:

```
double dispMax(int farray[], int maxValue)
{

    int max = farray[0];

    for (int x = 0; x < maxValue; x++) //maxValue is size of farray
    {

        if (farray[x] > max)
        {

            max = farray[x];
            return max;

        }

    }

}
```

The farray[] is unsorted, and composed of just a list of  data types (E.g (123.25, 234.3, 345.12)).

Sometimes it seems like it doesn't even iterate throughout the entire array, almost as if it just finds something it considers a max value, then immediately returns that one instead.

Also, if I adjust the function to find a minimum value instead, I get a similar result of being ALMOST the minimum value, but not quite.

Any help is appreciated greatly!

Comment: `maxValue is size of farray` Great name! Anyway, you could figure this out easily with a debugger.

Comment: Put `return max` out of the loop. That's all.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You should iterate through whole array before returning the max value.

Comment: 123.25 is not an `int`.

Comment: Return the **max** value once you have iterated whole array. So, remove return inside loop and place at out of loop.
Also, Since you assigned fArray[0] initially you can loop the array from the index 1. Or either you can use **std::max_element** to find out max value in array

Comment: Thank you all! I don't know why, but my mind made up that it needed to be in the loop even through the debugging, and I just never thought to move it out! 

I will be much more cautious next time. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The return is in a wrong place

Supose the array is 1 2 3

so max = 1;

Then when it goes for the second value

farray[1] = 2 it is bigger than 1 so return (?)

Put the return outside the for loop, let the loop traverse all the array

```
double dispMax(int farray[], int maxValue)
{
    // need to be double
    double max = farray[0];
    for (int x = 0; x < maxValue; x++) //maxValue is size of farray
    {
        if (farray[x] > max)
        {
            max = farray[x];    
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```